# Matlab-like command history retrieval in unix command line

Tags: matlab, unix

In Matlab, there is a very nice feature that I like.  Suppose I typed the command `very-long-command`  and then a few several commands afterwards.  Then later if I need the long command again, I just type `very` and press the up arrow key, my long command appears.  It finds the last command that starts with `very`. I couldn't do the same in unix command line,  when I try to do it, it disregards whatever I typed, and goes back to the last commands in chronological order.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Matlab has good default settings. I always wonder why the Unix people can't provide good default settings for these things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In bash, hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>  will let you do a history search:

```
$ echo 'something very long'
something very long
$ # blah
$ # many commands later...
(reverse-i-search)`ec': echo 'something very long'
```

In the above snippet, I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> on the next line after `# many commands later...`, and then typed <kbd>e</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> which brought me back to the echo command.  At that point hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> will execute the command.

Comment: Thanks! I have another quick question, what if there are two recently used long commands starting with echo, how can I switch between the two with this method?

Comment: @AgCl: [This blog post](http://ronny.haryan.to/archives/2005/03/14/tip-history-search-in-bash/) explains how to set up `history-search-forward` and `history-search-backward` to navigate through the history.

Comment: The above link is dead

Answer (score 12):

In bash this functionality is provided by the commands history-search-forward and history-search-backward, which by default are not bound to any keys (see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html)). If you run

```
bind '"\e[A":history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B":history-search-forward'
```

it will make up-arrow and down-arrow search backward and forward through the history for the string of characters between the start of the current line and the point. See also [this related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030182/how-do-i-change-bash-history-completion-to-complete-whats-already-on-the-line).

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same thing by using "!". For example:

```
 $ echo "Hello"
 Hello
 $ !echo
 echo "Hello"
 Hello
```

However, it is generally a bad idea to do this sort of thing (what if the last command did something destructive?). If you expect you will reuse something, then I suggest you create a shell script and save it away somewhere (whenever I plan to reuse something, I create a script in ~/.local/bin).

Comment: Thanks, it's almost as close to Matlab's, but I can't see the whole command before hitting enter.  I'll upvote the answer when I have enough rep.

Comment: !echo:p 

will display the command (bash anyway) and you can choose to execute it or not.