# Changing ubuntu terminal's up-down arrow

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

How can I make up/down arrow in ubuntu's terminal scroll up and down only commands that begin with what I've already typed?
for example, if I entered these commands:

% bla

% do this

% do that

and then, I enter bl[up arrow], I want it to show me "bla" and not "do that" first.

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a nice feature request for xterm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this right?

```
# ~/.inputrc
"\e[A": beginning-of-history
```

[Here is the table of escape sequece.](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)
And Cursor Up is on the top.

[And there are some interesting commands.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html)

Reference:

[How do I change bash history completion to complete what's already on the line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030182/how-do-i-change-bash-history-completion-to-complete-whats-already-on-the-line)

Comment: The correct option was 'history-search-backward' but thanks for the links.

Comment: Is there a possibility to add a command after it? I want to to both do 'history-search-backward' and move to the end-of-line. How can I put two commands on a single line?