# Is there a way to allow spaces in bash bang pattern (repeating last command)

Tags: bash, repeat

I was wondering if there is a way to repeat a bash command with a subcommand separated by space. For example, if I enter several commands,

```
git add a.txt
git status
... other commands starting with git
git commit -m ""
```

and do:

!git

I will run the last `git commit` command again. My questions, is there a way to repeat the last command that contains a space, e.g. to repeat the last `git status` command?

I tried,

```
!git\ s
!"git s"
```

, but none works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
!?git s
```

The "!?*string*" event designator searches for the [most recent command preceding the current position in the history list containing string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html).

Also you could use this to refer to the command n lines back:

```
!-n
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this on mingw/msys. It did not work. But it works on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you could hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> , type "git s" then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

*Though related, but not exactly answering your question ...*

Try adding the following two lines to your `~/.bashrc`

```
bind '"\e[A":history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B":history-search-forward'
```

**FUNCTIONALITY** (after you `source ~/.bashrc` or open a new terminal):

- when you start typing i.e. "git" and hit the up or down arrow, it will search through your history completion to complete what's already on the line.
- [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030182/how-do-i-change-bash-history-completion-to-complete-whats-already-on-the-line)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`fc` bash builtin command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html):

```
$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
$ git diff
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>
$ fc -s 'git s'
git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
$
```