# escaping a string with special characters and single quotes in a dockefile run instruction

Tags: bash, docker, shell, dockerfile

I am trying to append to lines to the .bashrc in a Dockerfile for a VS Code devcontainer. But I am not able to preserve the string as they are.

```
bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
```

My most recent attempt looks like this, but I have already tried a couple different variants using backticks and so on.

```sh
RUN echo "bind '\"\\e[A\": history-search-backward'" >> /home/local-user/.bashrc \
 && echo "bind '\"\\e[B\": history-search-forward'" >> /home/local-user/.bashrc
```

Comment: The cleanest solution would be storing the two lines in a `histsearch_binds.sh` file and concatenating this to the end of `.bashrc` with : `RUN cat histsearch_binds.sh >> /home/local-user/.bashrc`

Comment: Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030182/how-do-i-change-bash-history-completion-to-complete-whats-already-on-the-line

Comment: How does this solve my problem @ArnaudValmary?

Comment: @TheFool Instead of modifying `.bashrc`, add a `/home/local-user/.inputrc` file on your image

Comment: @ArnaudValmary, it works fine in the bashrc, this question is about escaping the string. Since it needs to be echoed. I had the same problem with any other file such as .inputrc.

Comment: @LeaGris : Why modifying .bashrc on the fly? One could include the correct .bashrc into the container.

Comment: @user1934428 or one doesnt want to use an extra COPY instruction and create unwanted extra layers as side effect nor clutter the local system with extra files in order to build a dev container.

Comment: @ArnaudValmary this happens when I do it in .inputrc, it breaks something `source /my-project/.venv/"": history-search-forwardin/activate  bash: /my-project/.venv/:: No such file or directory` . Working fine with bashrc for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `echo` in Dockerfile interprets `\e` to ^[ (ESC character), so you need double escaping :

```
RUN echo "bind '\"\\\\e[A\": history-search-backward'" >> /home/local-user/.bashrc \
 && echo "bind '\"\\\\e[B\": history-search-forward'" >> /home/local-user/.bashrc
```