# Search command-line history for lines beginning with "git"

Tags: bash, shell, input-history

I tried this but it finds nothing:

```
history | grep "^git"
```

This finds too many lines:

```
history | grep "git"
```

Comment: See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030182/how-do-i-change-bash-history-completion-to-complete-whats-already-on-the-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `history` command shows numbers before the actual commands so try using this `awk` command instead:

```
history | awk '$2 == "git"'
```

Or

```
history | awk '$2 ~ /^git/'
```

You can also just search `~/.bash_history` but the contents of this file may not always reflect the current history:

```
grep '^git' ~/.bash_history
```

Comment: `history | grep "^\d+ git"` is also not working here. `history | grep "\d+ git"` is good but does not guarantee that it is looking for from the beginning. i prefer using `grep '^git' ~/.bash_history` next time.